# How do I do a simple ajax post with ScriptSharp 0.6 (C# to Javascript)?

Tags: c#, script#

ScriptSharp 0.6 turns C# to Javascript and looks pretty neat. However I don't have much experience with event handling in C# and I'm stuck on how to do this:

```
$.post("urlToPostTo", $("#testform").Serialize(),
   function(data){
     alert(data.name); // Something sent from the server
   }, "json");
```

That's a simple JQuery form post that returns an alert with the JSON return object as the success callback. For ScriptSharp it is setup like:

```
public static XmlHttpRequest Post(string url, object data, AjaxCallback callback);
```

With AjaxCallback defined as:

```
public delegate void AjaxCallback(object data);
```

It seems like I'd set something up along these lines:

```
JQuery.Post("urlToPostTo", JQuery.Select("#testform"), callbackhere);
```

I'm at a loss as to how to setup and define the callback in C#, any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code would be something like this:

```
JQuery.Post("url", JQuery.Select("#testform").Serialize(),
    delegate(object data) {
        Script.Alert(Type.GetField(data, "name"));
    });
```

Basically an anonymous delegate in c# gets translated to a function suitable for use as a callback. You can also write it as a regular method, and use a delegate to that method.

Hope that helps.